# How to display data in a listview without adding a set of data on top of another

Tags: c#, listview, windows-forms-designer

I try to display in a listview a workout plan depending of your level of fitnness. The problem is when I press more buttons, instead of displaying only the current workout plan, it displays the new one on top of the old one. I tried to remediate the problem by clearing the list object "plan" which is used to store the exercises every time I press a button.

```
private List <Exercise> plan = new List<Exercise> ();

public CaliGuide()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void beginnerbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    plan.Clear();
    plan.Add(new Exercise { Name = "Pushups", Frequency = 8, Sets = 3 });
    plan.Add(new Exercise { Name = "Australian Pullups", Frequency = 10, Sets = 3 });
    plan.Add(new Exercise { Name = " Pullups", Frequency = 4, Sets = 3 });
    plan.Add(new Exercise { Name = "Asisted one leg squat", Frequency = 5, Sets = 5 });
    plan.Add(new Exercise { Name = "Calf raises", Frequency = 15, Sets = 3 });
    plan.Add(new Exercise { Name = "Crunches", Frequency = 12, Sets = 3 });
    foreach(var item in plan)
    { 
        var lvi = new ListViewItem(new[] { item.Name, item.Frequency.ToString(), item.Sets.ToString() });
        listview1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

I have 2 other similar buttons, the only difference, they consist of different exercises.

Comment: `listview1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: can you be more specific, should i delete plan.Clear( ) ?